# How to hide gallery folder and show only the document using ACTION_GET_CONTENT in android?

Tags: android

I want to pick the xls and xlsx files from the device. I have used ACTION_GET_CONTENT, it showing all photos inside the gallery.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
String[] mimetypes = {"text/plain","application/pdf", "application/txt","application/msword","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
```

I don`t want Gallery files to be shown. How to achieve this...? Thanks in advance

Comment: And if you remove setType() statement?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);` with `(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);`

Comment: Nonsense. I think you have to use the menu there and activate it. Usually one only has to activate the SD card to become visible.

Comment: @greenapps i set my ``Intent.setType`` to ``("file/*");`` and Replaced the intent with ``(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);``  it does show documents only . but if you open the gallery section then sure you are going to get images..

Comment: `it does show documents only` Can be. At startup. But of course the user can click to get to the root of all possible trees.

Answer (score 0):

> I have used ACTION_GET_CONTENT, it showing all photos inside the gallery.

Well, `*/*` matches everything.

> I don`t want Gallery files to be shown. How to achieve this...?

Replace `*/*` with one of your other MIME types, <strike>removing that one from the `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES` list</strike>.

Comment: That should be done indeed. After that it disables most files. It shows .pdf files selectable. But not .txt files. Even after i changed "text/plain" to "text/*". Which mime type is missing?

Comment: @greenapps: Since I do not have any of your code, I have no idea. In general, I would expect `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES` to be ignored on Android 4.3 and older devices. I would not be surprised if support for `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES` on `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is shaky for some devices that got upgraded to Android 4.4+ from 4.3 or older.

Comment: Found the solution for Priya's problem and Priya's code. `removing that one from the EXTRA_MIME_TYPES list.` That should not be done. setType() has to be used for one. But all mimetypes have to be in the list. So indeed one is double. Then it works. .txt and .pdf is shown now.